# QlikView/QlikSense: Transforming Column with Lots of Strings

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the following structure as input in Qlik, comprising two columns. The first column (index) contains sequentially increasing numbers, while the second column, which requires transformation, consists of a series of strings separated by a character (in my case, a space).

What I aim to achieve is a transformation where, for each index, every string in the second column is repeated.

To illustrate, consider the following example using chapters of a book and words. The second column contains all the words of a book:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I want to emphasize that the challenge lies in handling multiple strings in the second column during this transformation. Creating an intermediate table with columns corresponding to individual strings is not feasible because there can be hundreds of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`SubField()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm), which lets you split a string by a delimiter. Normally you would also specify which *nth* substring you want to be returned but in the Data Load Editor, you can actually ignore that parameter, which will return each substring in a new record.

Here's the script you can use:

```
[data]:
Load
    [Index]
  , SubField([Col], ' ') as NewCol
Resident [data load];
```

That returns the data how you need it:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense result table]

A similar way to achieve this would be to add in the [`SubStringCount()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubStringCount.htm) and the [`IterNo()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/CounterFunctions/IterNo.htm) with the use of the `while` clause. Using those elements in combination allowing you to iterate over a given row, creating a new row for each iteration.

Given this example:

```
[data]:
Load
    [Index]
  , SubField([Col], ' ', IterNo()) as NewCol
Resident [data load]
  While IterNo() <= SubStringCount([Col], ' ') + 1
;
```

...we're saying that we want to iterate over a given row as many times as the space character `' '` appears in the `[Col]` field for that row. We add `1` to that expression since we assume there will always be one more substring than spaces. The `IterNo()` function returns the current iteration number, so we use as our argument for the **field_no** parameter, which is the third parameter in our `SubField()` function (the one we omitted in our first example).

So, since there are two spaces in `We went tiptoeing`, we loop over the row 2+1 times, each iteration looking like this:

`SubField( 'We went tiptoeing' , ' ', 1)` = `We`

`SubField( 'We went tiptoeing' , ' ', 2)` = `went`

`SubField( 'We went tiptoeing' , ' ', 3)` = `tiptoeing`